# Angular 9 - Problema de asincronía

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema de asincronía dentro de mi proyecto de angular, sin embargo no encuentro el error.

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subheaderService.setTitle('Creacion de Equipo');
    this.subheaderService.setBreadcrumbs([ { title: 'Mantenimiento - Registro - Equipo'} ]);

    this.createForm();
  }


createForm() {
    this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
     
      Marca: [0, Validators.required],
      
    });

    this.dataForm(); 
  }

dataForm(){
   
     this.mantenimientoservice.getMarca().subscribe(
       (data: any) => {
         this.arrayMarca = data;
         this.form.controls.Marca.setValue('0001');

         console.log("se seteó el marca en 1")

       }
     )

    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => { 
      const Id = params.id;
      this.title_page = (params.id && params.id > 0)? "Editar":"Nuevo";

      if (Id && Id > 0) { this.setObj(Id); }

      
    });

  }

setObj(Id){ const ctrl = this.form.controls; 
    this.mantenimientoservice.getEquipoById(Number(Id)).subscribe(
      (data: any) => { 

        var obj = data[0];

        ctrl["Marca"].setValue(obj.Marca);

        console.log("llegó marca web response")

        this.arrayDeta=obj.Documentos;

        this.updatePerteneceA();
        this.updateBaja();
        this.updateDeta();

      }, ( errorServicio ) => {
        console.log(errorServicio);
      }
    );
  }
```

Y cuando no tengo latencia (en local) todo va bien, me setea la marca correctamente, sin embargo cuando activo la opción de Slow 3g en las dev tools me salta los siguientes console logs:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O sea que primero llega la respuesta del backend; no entiendo cómo podría solucionarlo. Tengo otro formulario que tiene la misma estructura e incluso con más datos a traer desde el backend y funciona sin problema.

Answer (score 0):

Eso se soluciona asegurando el orden de ejecución. Puedes agregar un código que se ejecute luego de finalizado el primer observable:

```
dataForm(){
  this.mantenimientoservice.getMarca().subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      this.arrayMarca = data;
      this.form.controls.Marca.setValue('0001');
      console.log("se seteó el marca en 1")
    }
    // siguiente llamada
    .add(() => nextOperation())
}


nextOperation(){
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    const Id = params.id;
    this.title_page = (params.id && params.id > 0) ? "Editar" : "Nuevo";
    if (Id && Id > 0) { this.setObj(Id); }
  });
}
```